# how to upload an image using servlet to an absolute path

Tags: image, jsp, servlets, apache-commons

I want to upload a file to my project folder. My code is as follows:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    File savedFile;
    String destination;

    List<FileItem> items = null;
    try {
        items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (FileItem item : items) {
        if (item.isFormField()) {
            // Process regular form field (input type="text|radio|checkbox|etc", select, etc).
        } else {
            // Process form file field (input type="file").
            String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
            String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
            InputStream fileContent = item.getInputStream();

            String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("newUser");

            destination = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getContextPath() + "\\" + userName + ".jpeg";
            savedFile = new File(destination);

            //Check if file exists
            if(!savedFile.exists()) 
                savedFile.createNewFile();

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(savedFile));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            //Read from file and write to new file destination
            while((len = fileContent.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            //Closing the streams
            fileContent.close();
            bos.close();

        }
    }

}
```

When I run the jsp file and browse and select the required image and submit the form, the servlet runs but it throws IOException. The exception is throws by the line where I create a new path using **savedFile.createNewFile()**. Before I used that code, it threw another FileNotFoundException. I am not sure if the path that I have provided is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `getRealPath()` method.

```
 String fileName="/" + userName + ".jpeg";
 destination = getServletContext().getRealPath(fileName);
 savedFile = new File(destination);
```

Comment: **userName** is a string value that I accessed from the session object which is returning null. It's value is set in another servlet but I'm not sure why it's returning null. Could it be the effect of encoding type? But the session object should still be available throughout the session. Isn't it?